# "Noted. Thank you" as an answer to a letter informing about task completion? I mean office correspondence

Tags: sentence-construction, politeness, correspondence

Is it correct and polite to end business letter with "Noted. Thank you" as an answer to a letter informing about task completion?

Comment: This is brief, but that does not make it impolite.

Comment: It is extremely curt. Although nothing about the words is overtly impolite, the brevity of the message might be interpreted as cold, impersonal, or insincere. This kind of brevity in an email might not be deemed impolite because many use emails as mere notes. But a formal letter of 3 words is almost certain to be viewed as insulting.

Comment: I often end business emails that way to people or companies with whom I often correspond but my choice would always depend on the situation and individuals concerned. In general, they know me and that my response is not intended to be anything but confirmation that I have received their message.

Comment: It is not just its brevity which makes the response seem cold. Saying "noted" is a way of acknowledging a message without revealing what one thinks about it. It is like saying "I shall give your proposal the attention it deserves." It could mean "I think this is important and will give it serious consideration." or it could mean "I intend to throw it into the trash can the moment you leave the room." Rather than saying "noted" it is better to express approval: "Thank you for taking care of this problem." or say how one intends to act: "Thank you. I'll let the the team know."

Comment: I find nothing at all wrong with this. But if you're asking if it's polite or not, that's a matter of opinion (as the contrary responses have indicated), and you're not going to get a good answer.

Comment: I don't think I can acknowledge a mail saying 'noted' to my seniors in the office. They may get offended. In some typical Indian offices, even 'please' won't please them; but kindly, request you to kindly, or even 'humbly request you to kindly...' ;)

Comment: @RamPillai what about the same message to your peers, or to your subordinates? Or to an unsolicited announcement from someone trying to sell you services?

Comment: @Davo, It works the same way for almost all, except say to the juniors/ subordinates. Even peer group, or those senior by just a layer consider 'please' is not pleasing enough.  ;) I work for a university, but my efforts to communicate with the PhDs have suffered because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Brevity in writing can be mistaken as impolite because there is not enough material to determine tone, so the reader can find a tone (based on their expectations or personal biases) that is different from what the writer intended. Brevity in speech doesn’t have the same problem because the listener can hear the speaker’s tone directly rather than having to guess it from the words chosen.

Also, brevity of words can be interpreted as brevity of thought: if you didn’t put much effort into your response, then how much thought did you put into what you responded to?

Both of these factors can be canceled out if the person you’re replying to knows this is just your personality/style, but strangers don’t have that benefit.